# FastObjectListView UpdateObject() randomly reorders rows within primary sort

Tags: vb.net, winforms, objectlistview

1. Data is a generic List of domain objects.
2. I click the "Deploy Status" column header to sort on that column.
3. I have a button that does nothing more than folv.UpdateObject(someObject) .
4. Every time I press that button, the Deploy Status column maintains its sort, but all rows within the sorted blocks are randomly reordered, as per screenshot.

I have commented out everything in the form's code beyond loading the data, the test button, and the FastObjectListView's column.Add() and .SetObjects(). There are no event handlers wired up for the FastObjectListView. I am not setting PrimarySort or SecondarySort in code; only by clicking with the mouse.

[image: random reordering]

Comment: Is this a custom sort? Could you show the code where the sort is done?

Comment: What `IEnumerable` are you using for `SetObjects` have you passed true/false for `preservestate` boolean argument?  If there is any multithreading in your `IEnumerable` then it could possibly produce this behaviour?

Comment: Also do your objects have sensible `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementations?

Comment: Very likely an issue with how the FastObjectListView remembers the order of the model objects/rows internally. ObjectListView probably works just fine? The FastObjectListView extends the VirtualObjectListView (which does not support sorting) and kind of implements this as a feature on top of it. If you do not have thousands of rows, I would recommend using the classic OLV.

Comment: Mary: Not sorting in code.
Thomas N: plain old List(Of MyObj), so no threading.
I didn't need to worry about this in the end, but for future refrence my class did not override GetHashCode or Equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix this problem by either calling `Sort` after your button's call to `UpdateObject` or changing your usage of `UpdateObject` to `RefreshObject`

**Reproducing the problem (C# Repro for the issue in the API)**

This seems to reproduce the problem you are having. Run the code, sort the Other column ascending.  Click the update button.

```cs
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

        var OLVa = new FastObjectListView();
        OLVa.Width = 250;
        OLVa.Height = 250;
        OLVa.Columns.Add(new OLVColumn("ID", "ID"));
        OLVa.Columns.Add(new OLVColumn("Other", "Other"));

        var l1 = new lolz(1, 3);

        OLVa.AddObject(l1);
        OLVa.AddObject(new lolz(2,3));

        this.Controls.Add(OLVa);
        var btn = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Update",
            Top = OLVa.Bottom
        };
        btn.Click += (s,e)=>OLVa.UpdateObject(l1);

        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    private class lolz
    {
        public int ID;
        public int Other;

        public lolz(int id, int other)
        {
            ID = id;
            Other = other;
        }
    }
}
```

**Fixing the problem**

The following would fix it for the above example:

```cs
btn.Click += (s,e)=>
            {
                OLVa.BeginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    OLVa.UpdateObject(l1);
                    OLVa.Sort();
                }
                finally
                {
                    OLVa.EndUpdate();
                }
            };
```

Comment: This is a vb.net question.

Comment: So it is, sorry about that.  I have edit the answer to put the solution up front in generic language (at the top of the answer).  I've left the C# repro since it does show that it's a real issue.

Comment: Your repro example didn't exhibit the problem on my box, but I can confirm that "changing your usage of UpdateObject to RefreshObject" DID fix it. Thanks.